# how to add link or button click loader in android webview loaded website

Tags: java, android, webview, android-developer-api

i am build a web view android app with loader but i want when user click on web view web site any link or button then show loader till response comes so how can do it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }
    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example how to solve your problem. WebChromeClient provide loading listener.More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html).

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            if (newProgress == 100)
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else {
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i need to impliment on this above code

Comment: copy and paste mostly

Comment: this code all form android developer site provide by google

Comment: you just implement this code in above code

Comment: yes, u need just add this part of code to yours

Comment: thanks im done this...